# Fetching filename of a PHP file

Tags: php

I'm trying to fetch the filename of my php file.
Out of curiosity i was wondering if there are any alternative way of doing this besides.

```
echo "<br/>".basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Answer (score 5):

Php has a magic constant that return the file path : `__FILE__`

if you only want the file name, use `basename(__FILE__)`

The advantage is that it will work even for a php script called via CLI and not executed by a web server / cgi.

[See more here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: But that returns the filepath and not just the filename

Comment: use basename to get the file name only : `basename(__FILE__)`